# Selenium Python automation - Cannot find upload button/input type="file"

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I'm trying to locate an element with input type="file", however after researching many different approaches and ways to simply locate an element on the page based on XPath, CSS selector, Tag, etc. The script encounters a NoSuchElementException. The element is in an iFrame.

The exception is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.jsx-2404389384"}
```

The code that caused the exception is:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='div.jsx-2404389384')
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks

EDIT:
The actual element on the webpage is:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" class="jsx-2404389384 " style="display: none;">
```

Sorry the element WAS in an iframe... I've been trying different ways to solve this problem that I must have looked over the iframe part :|

Comment: I've viewed the element with the Chrome inspector so it's definitely there (I've edited the post to include the HTML of the element)

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate that element based on it type, not on it class name since the class name appearing here seems to be a dynamic value.
Try this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file'][accept*='video']")
```

The same with XPath:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file'][contains(accept,'video')]")
```

Also, I hope you understand that you will need to send the absolute path of uploaded file as a string to this element, like this:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file'][contains(accept,'video')]").send_keys("C:\images\imageupload.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your locator uses the wrong HTML tag.
`div.jsx2404389384` would locate an element with a `<div>` tag and `class=jsx2404389384`.

You want to locate an element with an `<input>` tag, so

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.jsx-2404389384')
```

should work, assuming there is only one `<input>` element with that class. If there are multiple, you would need to use `driver.find_elements` and find the right one out of the list of `<input>`s with `class=jsx-2404389384`.

Second, it does look like that class looks like it might be automatically generated and/or subject to change, so a CSS selector using attribute matching, like

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, input[type='file'][accept*='video'])
```

is better. That will find  tags with `type` attribute matching `'file'` and `accept` attribute containing `'video'`.

For more information, the [Selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) link to a great resource on [CSS selectors](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors). The latter link will give you more information about more advanced and specific CSS selectors, if you need them. For way more, there is the [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Answer (score 0):

The element was in an iframe so I just had to switch to the iframe and then the original XPATH, CSS, etc code worked.

I appreciate the answers anyway!